# Picard Theorem for functions which are locally Lipschitz - Sketch of proof

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have to prove the Picard-Lindelof theorem:

Let $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open sets and let $f:I\times U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous and Lipshitz continuous by $y$ and $(x_0,y_0)\in I\times U$; then the Cauchy problem:
$$y'(x)=f(x,y(x)),\; \; y(x_0)=y_0$$
has a unique local solution if $f$ is differentiable.

I have found a lot of proofs that use terms from Banach spaces and etc. Can someone give me a sketch of how to prove this without using Banach spaces and fixed points?

Comment: Look up, e.g., in the book by Hartman, ODE.